# Xampp close when user log off

Tags: xampp, windows-server-2012

I installed Xampp on Windows Server 2012. It works great, however when I log off the computer (not shut down) the Xampp shuts down and the domain becomes unaccessible from Internet

How can I solve this problem, I want the Apache and MySQL service to keep running even when I log off

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For those looking for a solution

try to register Apache and MySQL as Windows service (red cross in the XAMPP control panel)

Stop Apache and MySQL first, then click on the Red Cross to install the services. Done,